# Python append in loop working mystery

Tags: python

I found some "mystery" problem when I'm trying filling list in "for in" loop.

Here is example:

```
>>> params = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> el = {'param':0}
>>> el
{'param': 0}
>>> list = []
>>> for param in params:
...     el['param'] = param
...     list.append(el)
... 
>>> print(list)
[{'param': 5}, {'param': 5}, {'param': 5}, {'param': 5}, {'param': 5}]
>>>
```

But I think result should be

```
>>> print(list)
[{'param': 1}, {'param': 2}, {'param': 3}, {'param': 4}, {'param': 5}]
>>>
```

How to resolve this problem? And why real result isn't similar with result in my mind?

Comment: Your result is correct. `el` is a dictionary that gets uodated all the time on the value param. You are also storing a **reference** to this dictionary on the the list, hence the result

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Every element in your list contains a reference to the *same* dict. That is why you are seeing the same number in every element. Perhaps you want to do:

```
params = [1,2,3,4,5]

a = []
for param in params:
    el = {'param': param}
    a.append(el)
```

Also, be careful of shadowing builtins such as `list` with your variable names.

Comment: Thanks! But if haven't chance to create new el object in each iteration? Can I say python that I want value not reference?

Comment: No. Python only works with references. If you want to copy the value, you must do so explicitly (either creating a new object, or using the `copy` method)

Answer (score 2):

`el` refers to the same dictionary throughout, and `list.append(el)` adds a *reference* to that dictionary, not a copy of its current value, to the list. You don't have a list of 5 different dictionaries, but a list of 5 references to one dictionary.

To see what is happening in closer detail, print `list` and `el` each time through the loop. You'll see a growing list that always refers to the current value of `el`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the same dictionary for each entry in your list.  To fix this problem, add `el = {}` above `el['param'] = param` in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You modify the same `dict` in every iteration and add it to the `list`. You'll get the other result when adding copies of this dict to the `list`.

Just call `list.append(dict(el))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have one dict object that you are modifying.  You add a reference to that one dict to your list multiple times.  So your list contains 5 references to the same dict object.